# Django Rest Framework: What should I use for authentication? How should I use it?

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication, mobile-application

I just watched [this video](https://youtu.be/pYeekwv3vC4) about why JWT's suck. I'm now uncertain what I should use for authentication.

For context: The API I wrote is mainly used by mobile Apps (iOS and Android). In the future it will also be accessed via a React Frontend.

In the past I just used DRF's build in Token authentication. The phone would then just store this token in the storage of the respective app.

Now I've recently been told, that this is not safe and that I should use JWT's. While researching JWT's I found the video above, which elaborates on why JWT's suck and basic session authentication is better. But as far as I know, when used as an API I can't use session authentication with DRF, can I?

So my question is? What tools of DRF would you suggest to use for authentication, so that it's safe?

Thank you in advance if anyone answers this question!

Edit: Someone privately suggested using O-Auth instead of DRF's tokens or JWT's. Would that be better?

Comment: Try to use Oauth2 for API authentication in drf .

Comment: That's what I heard too. The only bad thing about that is, that it increases the requests done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my duplicate of the question on security stackexchange. The man @rdegges himself has answered it. Enjoy! https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184855/django-rest-framework-what-should-i-use-for-authentication-how-should-i-use-it/184950#184950

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [django-oauth-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/rest-framework.html) for OAuth 2